# Role based authentication for webapi

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have following token generation code which is working fine for authentication without any role. I need to enable role based authentication :

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        double timeout = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Timeout"].ToString());
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthserverOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        //Token generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthserverOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
```

How is it possible to enable role base authentication to the above code

So that in my web api action if i put Authorize(Roles="Admin") i can allow or deny access with the roles.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code similar to the following (assuming your using apis since your doing token auth):

```
 public class WebApiAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext ctx)
    {
        //unauthorized code here
    }
    //or
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
       //is authorized
    }
}
```

Notice how your would inherit from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` instead of `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` in a mvc controller. Additionally your parameter for `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` would be of type `HttpActionContext` and not `AuthorizationContext` as in a mvc controller.

Now on your APIs you can use `[WebApiAuthorize(Roles = "role")]`

Comment: i am not in mvc, i am using web api and calling these web api using angular

Comment: This is written for web api